# How to get data from a Table if they exist in another Table C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a two tables Customers, and ConnectedCustomers. That means customers can connect with each other.

My question is how can I get all Customers which are related to Chris (id = 3).

I should as a results get Bob and John..

I've tried something like this:

```
 query = _context.Customers.Where(c =>_context.ConnectedCustomers.Any(cc => cc.Connected_Customer1.Equals(3) || cc.Connected_Customer2.Equals(3)));
```

But this is not working it returns too many rows..

> Expected result for id 3 is BOB AND JOHN because they are connected
>   with id 3.

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: "But this is not working it returns too many rows" Can you add what it's returning and what you're expecting it to return?

Comment: @MindSwipe check for my edit, I wrote there about expected results. And right now I'm getting almost all companies the one who are not related to connected also.. and that's not good :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var answer = (from cc in _context.ConnectedCustomers
              join c1 in _context.Customers on cc.Connected_Customer1 equals c1.id 
              join c2 in _context.Customers on cc.Connected_Customer2 equals c2.id 
              where c1.id == 3 || c2.id == 3
              select c1.id == 3 ? c2 : c1
              ).ToList();
```

Comment: how this might look with Fluent Api syntax?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro, what problems with this syntax, it looks like SQL? With Fluent Api it will be less graphically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your query is you are querying from Customer table. When you are querying through Customer, what it's doing is getting all the possible combinations of Fk with Connected_Customer1 and Connected_Customer2 which satisfies the condition. 
What you should be doing is query from ConnectedCustomers.
Try this:

```
var result = _context.ConnectedCustomers
  .Where(x => x.Connected_Customer1.Equals(3) || x.Connected_Customer2.Equals(3))
  .Select(x=>x.Customers)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You never use the id of the user to check (c), so you have to add a condition like this :

```
var query = _context.Customers.Where(customer => _context.ConnectedCustomers.Any(cc =>
    cc.Connected_Customer1.Equals(customer.Id) && cc.Connected_Customer2.Equals(3) ||
    cc.Connected_Customer1.Equals(3) && cc.Connected_Customer2.Equals(customer.Id))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_context.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == _context.ConnectedCustomers.Where(cc => cc.Connected_Customer1 == 3).Select(cc => cc.Connected_Customer2))
```

Try that.